# The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, iis, windows-7, .net-4.0

So yesterday i installed PHP and MySQL on my development machine. Since then i get the following error when trying to run one of my .NET projects:

The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

It references this line of the Machine.Config:

```
<add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

I have searched online, high and low and can confirm that my machine.config HAS the necessary connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="" />
```

Interestingly enough, i performed the exact same operation of installing PHP and MySQL on my production server (server 2008) and there is no problem there. My dev machine is Windows 7.

My whole dev machine is broken because of this. How can i repair the machine.config or fix it and resolve this problem? Has anyone experienced this before?

Nugs

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Maybe there is a web.config somewhere that contains:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    ...
</connectionStrings>
```

You might also want to double-check that you're looking at the right machine.config.  There are separate machine.configs for each Framework version, and also separate ones for the 32-bit and 64-bit framework.

Comment: So for some weird reason. A completely unrelated web.config file had: <connectionStrings><remove name="LocalSqlServer" /></connectionStrings>

Comment: Removing this seemed to do the trick. I had no idea that a web.config file that is not even in the project i am running can affect other projects?

Comment: @Nugs, look at the following MSDN article on ASP.NET configuration file hierarchy and inheritance to understand why your project inherited these settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx

Comment: Can you really survive without this site :-)  Two years ago I was having some issues with connection string and based on some suggestions, I added <clear/> tag and it  worked.  Fast forward, everything was working (and still working with this tag), except that today, after great struggle, I finally managed to upgrade the project to MVC4 and moved to VS2013 and this error.  I was searching for the term "LocalSQLServer" all over my hard drive so I could remove it.  Who could have thought that brilliant people at Microsoft would insert this thing when they see the "clear" tag. Thanks.

Comment: old post but I have the same issue - as long as the connectionString named LocalSqlServer is there - the site loads fine... If I delete the connection string, the error is back... How can I remove the LocalSqlServer connectionString line? I have tried <clear/> and <remove : I still can't delete the line without the error!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to keep `<clear />` at the top of my connection strings for various reasons, and while the solution of adding a dummy connection string called `LocalSqlServer` worked, I found it messy to keep it around for reasons of "I don't know why we need it, but app doesn't work without it".

My solution was to remove the `roleManager` line below, since it was leftover from old code and wasn't required anymore.

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once check IIS , right click default web API and then advanced settings and check the physical path you have given is correct or not . Is it point to correct path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).