# ASP.NET MVC 4 Database Errors

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have published my website to a webhost but i have some serious database problems. This is my errors

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Line 255:            <providers>
Line 256:                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
Line 257:                    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Line 258:                    connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
Line 259:                    enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line: 257
```

This is the connection string to my host :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(localhost);Database=ulprojec_******-***;uid=ulprojec_***;pwd=********a;" />   

</connectionStrings>
```

And this is my membership connection string which i got from microsoft's website but it still makes the first error occur:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SiteSqlServer"
      userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <add 
          name="SiteSqlServer" 
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
          connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer"
          applicationName="georgi-it"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          requiresUniqueEmail="false"
          passwordFormat="Hashed"
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
          passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

I would really really really apreciate any help as i am desperate already.

**EDIT: I Sorted this out**

I have this issue now:

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984507/the-connection-name-localsqlserver-was-not-found-in-the-applications-configura)?

Comment: I assume you've looked and your config file doesn't contain the string "attachdbfilename"?  That sounds like part of a connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Well if the error is the one that you are receiving this means that you are using connection string "LocalSqlServer" in the following piece:

```
<providers>
Line 256:                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
Line 257:                    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
**Line 258:                    connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"**
Line 259:                    enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
```

And here you are making a remove to the connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    **<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />**
    <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(localhost);Database=ulprojec_******-***;uid=ulprojec_***;pwd=********a;" />   

</connectionStrings>
```

I think you can see that you have a simple naming issue with the connection string.

Comment: yeah i figured that out, but now i have another issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using membership features, remove the membership, profile and roleManager tags from system.web section of the root web.cofig file. This helped me to resolved the issue.

Comment: What exactly should be removed and from where?